# Is wildcard LIKE more performant than a multiple boolean search in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have been building an API for for a website and the objects I am searching for have a LOT of true/false fields. Instead of creating a huge db structure to manage the options I thought about serializing them in a string similar to '001001000010101001' where 1 is true and 0 is false (I am talking about 100 different options). The other reason I am doing this is to have a clean database so that all of those fields get grouped in a single field (I already have serializer/deserializer).

Now in the search function, since not all of the options get searched at the same time, I was thinking about using a LIKE statement with wildcards.

For example I would do something like this:

`WHERE options LIKE '1_1__1__1___1%'` (The final wildcard is to reduce the number of _ wildcards so that only the beginning of the pattern gets matched. I would stop at the last checked options to check and % wildcard the rest).

Would this (on average because sometimes there might be 2 or 3 parameters selected and many times there might be all of them) be more performant than a multiple series of AND xxx AND XXX AND ....?

Or is there a way more efficient (and clean to maintain) way of doing this that I am completely missing?

Answer (score 0):

Let me discuss some of the items you bring up.

I understand the 0/1 approach.  I find it interesting that you chose to go with strings instead of numbers.  For up to 64 true/false value, a `BIGINT` (8 bytes) or something smaller would work.

Did you also want to test for false for some flags?  Your string mechanism makes that rather obvious.  (Your example should include a `0`.)

Searching with `LIKE` will be efficient *only* if there is no *leading* wildcard (`_` or `%`).  So, I would expect *most* of your queries to involve a full table scan.  Your serializer, plus the `b` prefix would work for setting the strings.

The integer approach that I am countering with would involve `&` and other boolean operations to test.  This would probably be noticeably faster.  This would necessitate a full table scan.

If there are other columns being tested in the `WHERE` clause, let's see them.  *They* will be important to performance and indexing.

Using numbers instead of strings would be slightly faster because of smaller size and faster testing.  But not a lot.

You can get some of the benefits of numeric by using the `SET` datatype.  (Again limited to 64 independent flags per column.)  The advantage is that you talk to the database via strings, not cryptic bit positions.

If this is a real estate app, consider a few columns like: `kitchen`, `bedrooms`, `unusual_items` (second dishwasher, jacuzzi), etc.  No matter how it is implemented (string, integer, SET), this suggestion won't impact performance much.

Another performance note, again with a real estate model:  Since #bedrooms is almost always a criteria, make it a column by itself.  This may allow for some use of it in a composite index.